Solution space for $Ly := \ddot{y} + p(t)\dot{y} + q(t)y = 0$ is of $\dim = 2$
\begin{equation}\label{eqn1} 
Ly := \ddot{y} + p(t)\dot{y} + q(t)y = 0
 \end{equation}
I am following a book that have a proof for $\dim(S) = 2$ where $S$ is the solution space of second order homogeneous linear ODE. 
My question is how does non-zero Wronskian $(W)$ at $t_0$ implies that $W(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$? Does Wronskian like a continuous function defined on an interval? So if it is constant on one point implies it's a constant on whole interval. Pardon, if whatever I said does not make sense.

Preposition  3.3.3: $W \equiv 0$ if and only if $z$ and $w$ are dependent.


Preposition 3.3.2 basically says that any solution $y$ of the above equation can be written as the linear combination of the two linearly independent solutions.

EDIT:
The choice of initial conditions that author have, is also not clear to me. Why he chose the conditions to be $z(t_0)=1$,$\dot{z}(t_0)=0$
and $w(t_0)=0$,$\dot{w}(t_0)=1$ and will these conditions prove $W(t_0)$ to be non-zero for a general case? I may be missing some very obvious thing but i am not sure what's that.

The Wronskian is a solution the ODE $W'(x) = W(x)tr(A(x))$, where $A$ is the coefficient matrix of the system. Try to solve this, then you see why the claim holds.

@Iphil I got the implication why author says so. But I have never seen definition of Wronskian like you have mentioned. Wikipedia have a different definition. But after solving the equation that you have mentioned, solution looks like Abel's identity...

The choice of initial conditions that author have, is also not clear to me...why he chose the conditions to be $z(t_0) = 1, \dot{z}(t_0) = 0$ and $w(t_0) = 0, \dot{w}(t_0) = 1$ and will these conditions prove $W(t_0)$ to be non-zero for a general case? I may be missing some very obvious thing but i am not sure what's that.
